# Backbone -single page application - refetch and render module at every 2 seconds

Tags: backbone.js, setinterval, single-page-application

I have a single page backbone application with underscore templating. I am using a router to render modules for different hash-paths. For specific has-paths I need to re-fetch data via ajax and render again at every 5 seconds. How is the best way to do this ? Where to setInterval and where to clear it?. I would like to clear timeout when I navigate to other view or render other view in my main container.

Thanks for you're help !

Answer (score 1):

One part of your problem, setting an auto-refresh timer, is mentioned explicitly in the [Backbone docs for Model.fetch()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch):

```
// Poll every 10 seconds to keep the channel model up-to-date.
setInterval(function() {
  channel.fetch();
}, 10000);
```

Another part of your problem, updating the view when the model changes, can be solved by making your view listen for the `change` event fired by your model when the model receives new data:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  "initialize": function() {
    this.model.on("change", function() {
      this.render();
    }, this); // make sure to specify the proper context
  }
});
```

The last part of your problem, stopping the timer when the view is destroyed, can be solved by having your model listen for the router's `route` event which gets fired automatically whenever the user navigates to a new view:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  "routes": {
    "some/route": "goSomewhere"
  },

  "goSomewhere": function() {
    var model = new MyModel();
    var view = new MyView({
      "model": model
    });

    model.listenTo(this, "route", function() {
      // context here is the model object
      this.clearTimer();
    });
    view.render();
  }
});

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  "initialize": function() {
    this.timerHandle = setInterval(function() {
      this.fetch();
    }, 5000);
  },

  "clearTimer": function() {
    window.clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
  }
})
```

Comment: Does this mean that when I reach #some/route I will always create new model ? are this automatically cleared ?

Comment: yes, this code will automatically create a new model and view each time the user navigates to `#/some/route`.  Whether or not that's acceptable depends on you and your app; if you need to keep a reference to the old model, sure, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So the old model and view will hang on my DOM ? How I can clear them ?

Comment: call `Model.stopListening(myRouter, "route")` on the old model, and `View.remove()` on the old view.